# Duplicate date values on x-axis of bar chart in react-plotly.js

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I am implementing a bar chart using react-plotly.js. The x-axis of the chart is a timeline and it could happen that two bars has same x-axis values. Currently, when this scenario occurs, plotly doesn't draw the bars which has duplicate values. How do I fix it ?

The date values in my json object are in unix format which i convert to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format as plotly accepts just that particular format. so my input to chart looks like:

```
["2018-11-29", "2018-11-29", "2018-11-29", "2018-11-29", "2018-11-29", "2018-11-29", "2018-11-29", "2018-11-29","2018-11-28"]
```

As a result of the above input, I don't get any bars on chart with duplicate x values.

Is there any workaround for this issue ? Does plotly accept date in any other format ? As in if I include time along with date will that be of any help ?